# SQL Server LIKE on datepart doesnt work for the time element

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to return rows in my table that have a certain date but also a certain hour.

At the moment I can handle the date part of the query just fine by using:

```sql
CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), col1, 126) LIKE '2012-11-05%'
```

That works perfectly and returns all rows where col1 has a value of the 5th November. However when I also want to add the hour to the end like this:

```sql
CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), col1, 126) LIKE '2012-11-05 15%'
```

That query returns no rows, even though there are rows with the hour set to 15.

It looks like the time element of the query needs some kind of different syntax? I just wondered if anyone can confirm this?

Comment: You should check the interval instead. `col1 >= '2012-11-05T15:00:00' and col1 < '2012-11-05T16:00:00'`

Comment: Don't cast dates to string for this, there is no reason.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server:

```
create table #test(part varchar(10),lastTime datetime)
go

insert into #test (part ,lastTime )
values('A','2012-11-05 10:30')

insert into #test (part ,lastTime )
values('B','2012-11-05 15:00')

insert into #test (part ,lastTime )
values('A','2012-11-05 16:15')

go
```

select * from #test where CONVERT(varchar,lastTime,126)  like '2012-11-**05T15**%' ----OK

```
B   2012-11-05 15:00:00.000
```

select * from #test where CONVERT(varchar,lastTime,**21**)  like '2012-11-05 15%' ----OK

```
B   2012-11-05 15:00:00.000
```

select * from #test where CONVERT(varchar,lastTime,21)  like '2012-11-05 %15%' --had bug

```
B   2012-11-05 15:00:00.000
A   2012-11-05 16:15:00.000
```

consider perfermance:

```
select * from #test where lastTime  >= CONVERT(datetime, '2012-11-05 15:00:00') and lastTime  < CONVERT(datetime, '2012-11-05 16:00:00')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), col1, 126) LIKE '2012-11-05T15%'
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Format 126 returns ISO8601 yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmm (no spaces)